# sql - best design practice tables

Tags: sql

I need to create a system in which users can add cats or dogs but I'm not sure how to design tables to handle it.

First of all:

1. Users can add both dogs and cats
2. Dogs and cats have some different column required
3. Each of them have a race (as human race, I don't know if this is correct)

For example for dogs I need 2 specific fields, for cats I need other 2 specific fields and then I have about 5/6 shared fields.

Which is the best practice? Two different tables or just a single one with a column called `type` where:

type = 1 is dog
type = 2 is cat
and set `NULL` the specific fields that I don't need?

Same problem is for the dog's race and cat's race...is better a single table in which store all of them and separate them with a `type` column?
Or two different table are the correct way?

Comment: Using one table with all the columns is fine as long as there aren't too many empty/wasted columns. Personally, I'd prefer to have one pet table with the shared columns with two other tables for Cats/Dogs (PK/FK = PetID linking to Pet table). Either way, whatever you choose, try to keep it consistent across the rest of your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say : start simple. One table for the animals with a type column (it can be an explicit varchar like 'DOG' and 'CAT'), and one table for the races, with also a type column. It will be easier to plug an ORM on top of that, and easier to query if you have to run some statistics.

Only possible troubles with this is are :
- more and more columns that will be exclusive to one animal, leading to some heavy refactoring
- a possible mismatch between the TYPE columns of a Pet and its Race if the application messes with the data